# PySpark: get all dataframe columns defined as values into another column

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm newby with PySpark and don't know what's the problem with my code.
I have 2 dataframes

```
df1= 
+---+--------------+
| id|No_of_Question|
+---+--------------+
|  1|            Q1|
|  2|            Q4|
|  3|           Q23|
|...|           ...|
+---+--------------+

df2 = 
+--------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| Q1| Q2| Q3| Q4| Q5|  ...   |Q22|Q23|Q24|Q25|
+--------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  0|  1|  0|  0|  ...   |  1|  1|  1|  1|
+--------------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I'd like to create a new dataframe with all columns from `df2` defined into `df1.No_of_Question`.

Expected result

```
df2 = 
+------------+
| Q1| Q4| Q24|
+------------+
|  1|  0|   1|
+------------+
```

I've already tried

```
df2 = df2.select(*F.collect_list(df1.No_of_Question)) #Error: Column is not iterable
```

or

```
df2 = df2.select(F.collect_list(df1.No_of_Question)) #Error: Resolved attribute(s) No_of_Question#1791 missing from Q1, Q2...
```

or

```
df2 = df2.select(*df1.No_of_Question)
```

of

```
df2= df2.select([col for col in df2.columns if col in df1.No_of_Question])
```

But none of these solutions worked.
Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the values of `No_of_Question` into a python list then pass it to `df2.select()`.

Try this:

```
questions = [
    F.col(r.No_of_Question).alias(r.No_of_Question) 
    for r in df1.select("No_of_Question").collect()
]

df2 = df2.select(*questions)
```